# jQuery hasClass not behaving

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this always returning false when it shouldn't be? How do I get it to behave?

```
var originalDiv = $(clickedButton).parent();    
alert($(originalDiv).hasClass('.question_box_expanded'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.` before your class name. That's used for selectors only.

In order to debug this yourself, set a break point on that line. Then, step into the jQuery calls and look at what is happening. Somewhere along the way, it'd become obvious that the `.` was causing the issue.

Comment: Yeah I feel stupid you answered faster than I could hit delete. Took me 45 minutes to see that freaking dot.

Comment: @Preston Don't be like that. I make silly mistakes like this all the time.

Comment: haha thanks it's late and I'm hungry we'll chalk it up to that. I'll mark correct as soon as the new question timeout expires.

Comment: Alright let's head to the pub and get ourselves a pint to celebrate. "+1" if you agree.